# Entire function $f$ with infinitely many zeros

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function, non constant with the property: The set $\{w : f(w)=0\}$ has ininite elements. Show that for all c there exist a sequence $\{z_n\}$ such that $z_n\to\infty$ and $f(z_n)\to c$.

Anyone could please give me some help for this exercise? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the Casoratti-Weierstrass theorem to $g(z)=f\left(\frac1z\right)$. Note that if the Taylor series of $f$ at $0$ is$$a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots,$$then infinitely many $a_n$'s are non-zero, because otherwise $f$ would be either the null function (which is constant) or a non-null polynomial (which has only finitely many zeros). But then the Taylor series of $g$ at $0$ is$$a_0+a_1z^{-1}+a_2z^{-2}+\cdots$$ and therefore $g$ has an essential singularity at $0$.

Comment: Can I assume that g has an essential singularity in 0?

Comment: @Arturo No  You will have to prove it. But it is not hard.

Comment: So, if I delete the hypothesis "The set {w:f(w)=0} has infinite elements" it will still be truth? I didn't need to use it with the Casoratti-Weirstrass Theorem.

Comment: @Arturo  But you will need it to prove that $g$ has an essential singularity at $0$. And the statement is false without it. Just tame the identity function.

Comment: @Arturo Do you need a full answer?

Comment: Yes, please. I can't find any relation between the essential singularity in 0 and the existence of that set...

Comment: @Arturo  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Perfect, understood it. Thank you so much!

Comment: We could also argue that since $f$ has infinitely many zeros, it is not a polynomial. Hence it has an essential singularity at $\infty$, now apply CW.